# How to dynamically generate draggable component in angular material

Tags: angular

Trying to dynamically generate draggable components but apparently it's not working.

```
generateComponent(){
    this.d1.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="example-box" cdkDragBoundary=".example-boundary" cdkDrag>I can only be dragged within the dotted container</div>');
  }
```

The css is not rendered, the item is not draggable.